# .NET: Debug project in another language

Tags: .net, debugging

I have a VB.Net projects which calls some C# dll's, but how can I debug the C# code?

It must be possible, because when an exception occurs, VB.Net opens the C# code in a text-editor, but I want to be able to have syntax-coloring, set breakpoints in other files, etc. I feel it must be obvious, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: This should work.  Describe exactly what happens when you try to set a breakpoint.

Comment: The reason you are able to step into the C# code is probably because you have the .pdb files with the .dll file you've referenced. Not sure how to force it w/out adding project to your solution.

Comment: @HansPassant The breakpoints work for C# files that are already open, but to set a breakpoint in another file, I first must manually add it to the project. But maybe that's the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your debugging session normally.

Then once it is started, use Visual Studio, File/Open menu to open the correct .cs file. If you have a corresponding .pdb file for the dll in which the file is included you will be able to set breakpoints which will be hit in your debugging session.

If you don't have the pdb file, this means your dll was compiled in Release configuration rather than debug configuration.

During this session you may need to open other .cs files manually as you step into statements. Open the needed files before you step into them.

Comment: I already add the files manually, but the C# project has hundreds of files, so it's a lot of work. I just thought there was a way to add the whole project nicely into the solution, and have syntax-coloring, but maybe it's just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to running the projects (F5) and if you have the C# code (rather than just the PDB) you can open up the .cs file using File->Open and set breakpoints.

If you don't have the .cs then can use something like reflector to generate the .cs files for you.

It should also be possible to create breakpoints with just the PDB but I've only had success with that if I've already interrupted a running debug session.

Comment: I already add the files manually, but the C# project has hundreds of files, so it's a lot of work. I just thought there was a way to add the whole project nicely into the solution, and have syntax-coloring, but maybe it's just not possible.

Comment: Why not just add the project to your solution then

Comment: Because Visual Studio doesn't allow that? Maybe it's a limitation of VS Express, and mixed-language solutions are supported in the Pro version?